# Exact Differential Equations and The Constant of Integration for the Factor $\int g'(y) dy$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have an exact DE of the form

$M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0$,

then we solve it using the following steps:

1. Check exactness: $\dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} = \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}$? If yes, then proceed.
2. Assume that $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = M(x,y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} = N(x,y)$.
3. Integrate $M(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and add an arbitrary function of $y$, $g(y)$, as the integration constant. This gives us $f$.
4. Differentiate the result from step 3 with respect to $y$, which gives $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$, and compare with $N(x,y)$. Solve this for $g'(y)$.
5. Integrate $g'(y)$ with respect to $y$ to find an expression for $g(y)$. **Do not add an integration constant**.
6. Substitute $g(y)$ into the result obtained in step 3 to obtain $f(x,y)$.
7. The general solution is $f(x,y) = C$, where $C$ is our constant of integration.

A similar procedure can be stated so that in step 3, $N(x,y)$ is integrated with respect to $y$.

My question is, why do we not add an integration constant at step 5?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: You can add an integration constant (say, $C_1$) at step 5, and after step 6 you have $f(x, y) + C_1$.  Then the general solution would be $f(x, y) + C_1 = C$, with two arbitrary additive constants.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks for the response. This is what I thought, but I also thought I might have done something wrong. So, after we find $g(y)$, we would get $f(x, y) = M(x, y) + g(y) + C_1 = C \rightarrow f(x, y) + C_1 = M(x, y) + g(y) = C$ to be the general implicit solution for the DE?

Comment: But then my question is, how does this make sense? How can we have $f(x, y) + C_1$ as our implicit general solution to the DE? Doesn't the solution to the DE have to be just $f(x, y)$? It looks ... weird to the say that the implicit general solution to the DE is a function $f(x, y)$ PLUS a constant $C_1$?

Comment: Ahh, but that's why it's an **implicit** general solution, right? The **explicit** general solution would be $y = ...$, but since we're dealing with the *implicit* general solution, it's sensible/valid to say that it's $f(x, y) + C_1 = C$?

Comment: Since $C_1$ and $C$ are just constants, redefine the constant: $C \leftarrow C - C_1$. Unless there is some compelling reason to distinguish between constants.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I understand now. Thanks both of you for the clarification.